# Code First The ForeignKeyAttribute on property '' on type '' is not valid. EF 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to make database for sport application using Entity Framework 6.1.3 Code First. When I try to make database is throw me exception.

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'HomeTeamId' on type 'Match' is not valid. The navigation property 'TeamId' was not found on the dependent type 'Match'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

My Team class

```
public class Team
{
    private ICollection<Match> matches;

    public Team()
    {
        this.matches = new HashSet<Match>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches
    {
        get { return this.matches; }
        set { this.matches = value; }
    }
}
```

My Match class

```
public class Match
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 255)]
    public byte HomeTeamScore { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 255)]
    public byte AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two foreign keys....

```
AwayTeamId
HomeTeamId
```

They're both referencing

```
TeamId
```

EntityFramework should be able to figure out the relationships on it own from what you have, so try removing the `ForeignKey` attribute and attempt an update.

---

#### Or

Read the summary comments on `ForeignKeyAttribute`

```
/// <summary>
/// Denotes a property used as a foreign key in a relationship.
/// The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, 
/// or placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name.
/// </summary>
```

So... your foreign key attribute should be set up like this...

```
[ForeignKey("AwayTeam")]
[ForeignKey("HomeTeam")]
```

---

### Edit

I replicated your solution locally, removing the foreign key attributes and all other associated attributes, including the Id's themselves resolves the issue.

```
public virtual Arena Arena { get; set; }

public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

[Required]
[Range(0, 255)]
public byte HomeTeamScore { get; set; }

public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

[Required]
[Range(0, 255)]
public byte AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
```

As you can see, no AwayTeamId, no HomeTeamId

And this is what Entity Framework generates on the backend... You still have the one to many relationship, test it out, let me know if you have issues

[image: EF]

Comment: If I changed then I have another exception. "The property 'HomeTeamId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type."

Comment: Well what's the exception?

Comment: The property 'HomeTeamId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Comment: @evelikov92 Ok... try this... `[ForeignKey("HomeTeam")]` and `[ForeignKey("AwayTeam")]`

Comment: New exception "Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Matches_dbo.Teams_AwayTeamId' on table 'Matches' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."

Comment: Ok you're going to have to use the `modelBuilder` to explicitly state that you don't want cascade delete enabled

Comment: @evelikov92 Ok I've found a better way to go about this... read update

Comment: Is not make exception. But then is it possible to add team in match without using id. And in database is save records good.

Comment: Yeah Entity Framework does all of that behind the scenes :)